# Expectation of stochastically ordered random variables

Tags: order-theory, order-statistics

I'm reading the paper [Invariant directional ordering](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176348905), and I'm confused by two propositions.

The basic definition is
[image]

If it holds, then
[image]

My first question is, in proposition $(1.6)$, shouldn't it be $E_F\psi(X) \ge E_G\psi(X)$, given $F(x) \ge G(x)$?

And for the second one:
[image]
. Shouldn't the distribution function of $\psi(X)$ be $F(\psi^{-1})$? Why it says the distribution is $F\psi^{-1}$?

Comment: @joriki Sorry I included it by mistake. I'll correct it up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $(1.6)$ is correct as it stands. $F(x)\ge G(x)$ means that $X$ (the variable corresponding to $F$) tends to be *smaller* than $Y$ (the variable corresponding to $G$), since $F$ and $G$ specify the probability for the variable to be *less than* $x$, and this probability is always larger for $X$ than for $Y$.

For the second question, it’s not clear to me what you mean by $F(\psi^{-1})$; this is not a standard notation. The standard meaning of $F\psi^{-1}$ is composition of functions, so $F\psi^{-1}$ is the function $F\psi^{-1}:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,x\mapsto F(\psi^{-1}(x))$, and this is indeed the cumulative distribution function of $\psi(X)$. Perhaps this is also what you mean by $F(\psi^{-1})$, but that is not how this composition is conventionally denoted. Another conventional notation for it is $F\circ\psi^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, by using the notation $F\psi^{-1}$ I do mean $F\psi^{-1}(x)$, sorry for the bad notation.